# Why ie7 lacks of text-decoration: underline on mouse over?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why ie7 does not apply `text-decoration: underline` on mouse over ?

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--

.main{
     padding: 0 10px;
     height:45px;
     float:left;
     color:#191919;
     text-align:center;
     overflow:hidden;
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.main:hover{
     padding: 0 10px;
     height:45px;
     float:left;
     color:#191919;
     text-align:center;
     overflow:hidden;
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: underline;
}

-->
</style>


<li class="main" style=" float: right; ">
   <p style=" color: #555; cursor: pointer;">
      <a style=" color: #555; text-decoration: none;" href="test.php">TEST</a>
   </p>     
</li>
```

Comment: IE7 usage is so minimal I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: this doesn't directly apply but it has some comments on a similar issue|http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1395829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 7 implements `text-decoration` wrong in some situations: setting `text-decoration: none` on an inner element may prevent the underline set on an outer element from appearing under the inner element. It is intuitively understandable, but against the specification.

As a workaround, set the underline for both the outer element and the inner element.

For the messy code in the question, the minimal fix would be to add the following CSS rule:

```
.main:hover a { text-decoration: underline !important; }
```

In this fix, the `!important` specifier is needed because the inner element has `text-decoration` set in a `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing overflow to visible , just to see if it shows in ie7. And also add !important.

Also, you have a lot of extra lines in your hover that aren't necessary since they are the same as in your .main. So you can clean that up by removing those lines if you want.

```
.main:hover{
         padding: 0 10px;  //you don't need this line
     height:45px; // nor this one
     float:left; // nor this one
     color:#191919;  //nor this one
     text-align:center; // nor this one
     overflow: visible;
         list-style: none; // nor this one
         text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to apply the style on actual anchor tag?

```
a:hover{
     padding: 0 10px;
     height:45px;
     float:left;
     color:#191919;
     text-align:center;
     overflow:hidden;
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe with the newer versions of CSS, the text-decoration value was transformed from having only a single input to multiple i.e. the ability to use 'color, line, and style'. Using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) as a reference, it states that text-decoration is now considered a 'shorthand property' which is no longer supported in IE. More information is found on the link I provided in the text.

I think the alternative is to use text-decoration-style, which is more specific and should be supported.

I hope this is correct, if not.. I can delete it :)

Comment: The MDN page is very confusing as regards to browser support information. Surely the transmogrification to a shorthand in some CSS drafts does not change the way things work in IE 7!

Comment: I could only hope so, I was just unsure but it seems like you fixed the problem just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
text-decoration: underline !important;
```